# Выпадающий список Backbone

Tags: javascript, jquery, mvc, backbone.js

```
events:{
      'change #choice': 'choice'
    }, 
choice: function(){
            if($('#choice option:selected').val() == 'companyValue') {
                $('#bodyContract').html(this.ContractCompanyView.el);
            }

            else {
                $('#bodyContract').html(this.ContractPersonView.el);
            }
    }
```

Подскажите, есть выпадающий список, который подгружает содержимое.Как сделать по дефолту, чтобы подгружалось сразу содержимое ContractPersonView?

```
<select id="choice">
            <option value="companyValue" id="companyVal">1</option>
            <option selected="selected" value="personValue" id="personVal">2</option>
        </select>
```

Comment: Если вам дали исчерпывающий ответ - отметьте его как правильный, а не "зануляйте" свое сообщение редактированием.

Answer (score 2):

Создайте модель для ваших данных:

```
var FormModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults : {
        firstname : 'John',
        lastname : 'Smith',
        surname : 'Robert'
    }
});
```

Теперь создаем общий вид, который инициализирует наши формы и расширяет их базовыми функциями для работы с ними:

```
var CommonView = Backbone.View.extend({
    model : new FormModel(),
    initialize : function () {
        // создаем экземпляры форм:
        this.form1 = new Form({ el : '#form1' }); 
        this.form2 = new Form({ el : '#form2' });
    },
    eachFields : function (func) {
        _.each(this.inputFields, func, this);
    },
    // запись в модель:
    setModel : function (input) {
        var $input = $(input),
            attr = $input.attr('name');
        if (attr) {
            this.model.set(attr, $input.val());
        }
    },
    // запись в поля формы:
    setInput : function (input) {
        var $input = $(input),
            attr = $input.attr('name');
        if (attr) {
            $input.val(this.model.get($input.attr('name')));
        }
    }
});
```

Класс формы может выглядеть примерно так (разумеется, вы можете создавать разные классы, которые будут слушать и работать с общей моделью данных, которая описана выше):

```
var Form = CommonView.extend({
    events : {
        'click button' : 'setFields',
        'change input' : 'setFields',
    },
    initialize : function () {
        // кешируем поля формы
        this.inputFields = this.$el.find('input');
        // первичный рендер
        this.render();
        // слушаем изменения в модели и обновляем вид
        this.listenTo(this.model, 'change', this.render, this);
    },
    render : function () {
        this.eachFields(this.setInput);
    },
    setFields : function (evnt) {
        evnt.preventDefault();
        this.eachFields(this.setModel);
    }
});

new CommonView(); // запускаем!
```

Пример набросал тут: http://jsbin.com/gifuyakudo/3/